# Are priests of other religions allowed to take part in Kumbh Mela?

Tags: other-religions, kumbh-mela

Are [priests of other religions](https://www.facebook.com/RajivMalhotra.Official/photos/a.137731093046903.31225.137726233047389/639393519547322/?type=3&theater) allowed to take part in Kumbh Mela?

Or, is it only a confluence of Hindu saints?

[image]